# Pass html from text area box to function and display returned result

Tags: html, function, user-input

I am a beginner with html and am trying to put some pieces together but cant quite get them all to fit.

The project is(my project just for fun - not a school or work project):

get a line of text from the user  (and ultimately an integer representing a 'shift' val for the text) -
pass that text to a function in an external js file - the function modifies the text
and have the html page display the returned result.

Ideally I would like the returned result to appear in the same text area box it was originally typed into because part 2 will be to 'unsmash' that text with a different function call.

So Far,
I have the javascript file and it works fine. The function within is smash({string})
(ultimately it will be smash({string},{integer}) with both values queried from user).
I am able to call the function in the js file from the html page when I hardcode a text string into a getelementbyid box - and that works.

but I cant figure out how to pass the data from the text box to the function call and display it anywhere (which would be my next logical step) - let alone back in the text area box.

keep in mind that ultimately I want to also pass a second value (an integer input by the user) to the function as well (right now its hardcoded in the .js) so that may affect the method needed to do this first part.

Also, I dont know if this matters but I exit the javascript function with a 'return result;' command. Where var result contains the modified string - but I havent seemed to need to refer to that so far.

Here is my html code for this phase of the project. I appreciate any help you can give.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>ASCII SMASHER</h1>
<p>Enter text in the "Smash me" box.</p>
<p>Enter the smash factor" box.</p>
<p></p>
<p>Then click the "SMASH" button box.</p>
<p id="UI"></p>

<textarea name="ui1" rows="1" cols="30">
SIMPLY SMASHING!
</textarea>

(//// this is my attempt to send the text data to the function via a button ////
 //// as far as I can tell it doesnt work at all. It certainly doesnt display anything////)

<button type="button" onclick="smash()">SMASH</button>


<script src="smash2.js"></script>

<script>
(//// The line below does return the correct result for the hardcoded string below. So ////
 //// I know the basic call to the js function works at the lowest level. Frankly, ////
 //// I got the use of that line from another post here and dont really understand ////
 //// what it is doing. I see the function call plainly enough, and I know it is ////
 //// ultimately writing the return value to the screen, but that is as far as I get ////
 //// so if someone would care to take the trouble to explain what is going on with ////
 //// that, as well, I would take it kindly. ////)

document.getElementById("UI").innerHTML=smash("SMASHING");
</script>
</body>

<footer>
<p>"If you ask me you should stop all this smashing or
mashing of the atom, or whatever your doing"</p>
<p>(- The Absent-minded Professor - housekeeper)</p>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the function for `smash` defined?

Comment: Please post this code: `smash2.js`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you get a better understanding of the concept. I went ahead and imported the JQuery library ;)

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/q4Tpn/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Then click the "SMASH" button box.</p>
<div id="UI">
    <textarea id="uitext" name="ui1" rows="1" cols="30">SIMPLY SMASHING!</textarea>
</div>
<button id="button1" type="button">SMASH</button>


<script>
       $('#button1').click(function(){
           var temp = $("#uitext").val(); 
           $("#displayHere").text(temp);
       });

</script>

<div id="displayHere">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get the code you suggested to work and it works somewhat but doesnt appear to call the script - at least the value displayed is exactly what is entered in the box instead of the modified string that function smash() would produce.

Perhaps I made a mistake when I combined it into my code. Tho I tried to research the button.click portion of the code, I dont really understand how it is supposed to work, or how I specify that it is to call function smash() from smash1.js when I click.

Here is the current version of code I am trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
</head> 

<body>


<h1>ASCII SMASHER</h1>
<p>Enter text in the "Smash me" box.</p>
<p>Enter the smash factor" box.</p>
<p></p>
<p>Then click the "SMASH" button box.</p>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Then click the "SMASH" button box.</p>
<div id="UI">
    <textarea id="uitext" name="ui1" rows="1" cols="30">SIMPLY</textarea>
</div>
<button id="button1" type="button">SMASH</button>

<script src="smash1.js"></script>

<script>
       $('#button1').click(function(){
           var temp = $("#uitext").val(); 
           $("#displayHere").text(temp);
       });

</script>

<div id="displayHere">
</div>


</body>

<footer>
<p>"If you ask me you should stop all this smashing or
mashing of the atom, or whatever your doing"</p>
<p>(- The Absent-minded Professor - housekeeper)</p>
</footer>
</html>
```